# Python: Single record not shown, no idea why

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt

I have, what is most likely, a simple question.
I am building an application that uploads specifically formatted files to a MySQL database and does other things, but most notably it pretty much just displays the content of a database as you would expect of any database manager. However, I have just come across a very unusual thing. After having loaded in another file to add to the database, 1 single line of that file does not appear in the viewer whilst the rest does. No error is given during the upload, and having used the MySQL Workbench, it appears in there as it should. None of the datatypes are wrong (like 0000-00-00 00:00 in a date), and I can find no reason why this 1 file should be singled out.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info where Date_Out between '%s-01-01' and '%s-02-01' and commodity like '%s' order by Date_Out desc;"% (self.year, self.year, self.commodity))
    dataRows = cursor.rowcount
    rowOfData = cursor.fetchall()
    print len(rowOfData)
    #print rowOfData
    self.tableDatastring.setRowCount(dataRows + 1)
    rowNumber = 0
    u = 0
    currentItem = 0
    for i in rowOfData:
        for x in i:
            if u <= totalColumns:

                self.tableDatastring.setItem(currentItem,rowNumber,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(x)))
                u = u + 1
            else:
                rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
                self.tableDatastring.setItem(currentItem,rowNumber,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(x)))
```

To explain what it's meant to do. It counts the number of columns in the table and then it starts filling the returned results in 1 by one, but making sure that when it reaches the end of the line, it jumps to the next line (only way I could think about doing it).

Comment: I would suggest you look into PyQt Model View Programming , it will help you save time , and get rid of most of this code and its quite dynamic compared to widgets. look at this link [link](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8B63F2091D787896). if you want to look at an example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367370/how-to-insert-my-database-into-my-qtablewidget-table/21447250#21447250)

Comment: What is the line that doesn't show? Do the print statements in your example code display this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that you do not reset `u`, `currentItem` is always 0, also this is bad idea: "but making sure that when it reaches the end of the line, it jumps to the next line (only way I could think about doing it)." - that `else` could create new row where you do not expect it. `if u <= totalColumns:` ensures that it will stop when it reaches the end of the line, but you should know exactly how many columns you have (same number in database and in tableDatastring) so you do not actually need to check when it reaches the end of the line. So, try with this code:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info where Date_Out between '%s-01-01' and '%s-02-01' and commodity like '%s' order by Date_Out desc;"% (self.year, self.year, self.commodity))
dataRows = cursor.rowcount
self.tableDatastring.setRowCount(dataRows)
rowNumber = 0   
while True:
    oneRow = cursor.fetchone()
    if oneRow == None:
        break
    for columnNumber, columnData in enumerate(oneRow):
        self.tableDatastring.setItem(columnNumber,rowNumber,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(columnData)))
    rowNumber += 1
```

I, hope it helps.